# How to execute shell command inside a chroot jail

Tags: c, linux, shell, exec, chroot

I have a problem with the execution of shell commands inside a chroot jail. Here is an exemple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
   if (geteuid() == 0)    // check root privileges
   {
      chroot("/bin");
      chdir("/");

      execl("/ls", "ls", "-l",  (char *) NULL); // "/ls" should be equivalent to "/bin/ls"
      perror(strerror(errno));
   }

   else
      printf("Permission denied\n");

   return 0;
}
```

The problem is the exec: according to errno, the error is "No such file or directory".
The same error appears if I use exec("/bin/ls", ...)

I think that "ls" cannot use the shared libraries he needs, because of chroot jail.

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Works fine for me on the OpenBSD laptop I'm typing this on, for what it's worth, where running "ldd /bin/ls" tells me that it's a static executable. If you find that there are libraries needed, you'll have to fake up a way for them to be found under the chroot.

Comment: It could be as simple as an `ls` that lives in /usr/bin and has only a symlink to /bin. And as ataylor said below, chroot wants a real root environment with some libs in it's own /lib, /usr/lib and some files in /dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably right regarding shared libraries being inaccessible.  Setting up a chroot jail typically involves copying parts of `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/lib`, and `/usr/lib` into a parallel directory structure.

A simpler alternative is to use only statically linked executables.  On many linux systems there will be a statically linked executable called `busybox` that provides the base functionality of many Unix commands including `ls`.  Invoking it like `busybox ls -l` provides similar output to the regular `ls` program without needed to access addition shared libraries outside the chroot jail.